# How to mark over 17 thousand email messages read at once?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I have over 17,000 unread email messages in my Yahoo Mail inbox.

I tried to set all them as read by selecting *Select All* and then *More* → *Mark as read* (keyboard shortcut <kbd>K</kbd>) but it only marks less than a hundred every time. I want all of them to be marked as read at once. How can I do this?

I also tried searching using `is:unread` and then did the above procedure, but it did not seem to mark any messages as read in this case.

I am using the modern Yahoo Mail theme, not the classic one.

Answer (score 2):

If you have them all in Inbox, hover over Inbox in the left-side menu, click on the caret and then click on *Mark emails as read* from the drop-down menu.

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI, you should at least be in a Chrome web browser for the above to work. If you're using Internet Explorer, it doesn't display the drop down as shown.